# Echo site URL in src attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, url

I'm currently using Wordpress and when I start to use $_SERVER['SERVER NAME'] to retrieve the full path link. It seems didn't works for me as it didn't output the $_SERVER['SERVER NAME']. 
**Here my code ...**

```
<?php $SITE_IMAGE_URL = $_SERVER['SERVER NAME'].'/wp-content/uploads/2014/02'; ?>
<img class='widget-image' src='<?php echo $SITE_IMAGE_URL;?>/1.png'>
```

It returns `http://localhost/1.png` instead of `http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/1.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead to get the site url

```
site_url()
```

and your code will be like

```
$SITE_IMAGE_URL = site_url().'/wp-content/uploads/2014/02';
<img class='widget-image' src='<?php echo $SITE_IMAGE_URL;?>/1.png'>
```

hope this will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Correct way of doing this,

```
   $url = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";

    if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80")
    {
        $url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    } 
    else 
    {
        $url .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    }


    $SITE_IMAGE_URL = $url.'/wp-content/uploads/2014/02'; 

    ?>

<img class='widget-image' src='<?php echo $SITE_IMAGE_URL;?>/1.png'>
```